# DataBind Duration property of a DoubleAnimation

Tags: wpf, binding, storyboard

In short my quetion is: Can I use databinding for the duration property of a storyboard?

My intention was to design a circular progressbar where i have a simple counter. Now based on the counter I wanted to change the duration of the animation. Is there any way I can achieve this by databinding or is there any other way.

I am using an Arc to create the progressbar effect as you can see below. When the DependencyProperty PauseAnimation becomes false, my animation starts. When it is set to true, it resets(**I couldnt find a way to Pause the animation so I am resetting it to start from begining**). The below code runs perfectly but I am having trouble setting the duration of the storyboard. I want to change that based on a property in my control. Can I achieve this?

```
<ed:Arc x:Name="AnimatingArc" ArcThickness="2" ArcThicknessUnit="Pixel" StartAngle="0" EndAngle="360" Fill="{DynamicResource ApplicationPrimaryColour}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="25"  Stretch="None" Stroke="Transparent" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="25" Margin="8,47,0,0">
                    <ed:Arc.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ed:Arc}">
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding PauseAnimation}" Value="false">
                                    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                                        <BeginStoryboard>
                                            <Storyboard>
                                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="StartAngle" From="0" To="360" Duration="0:0:30" />
                                            </Storyboard>
                                        </BeginStoryboard>
                                    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                                    <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                                        <BeginStoryboard>
                                            <Storyboard>
                                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="StartAngle" To="0" Duration="0:0:10" />
                                            </Storyboard>
                                        </BeginStoryboard>
                                    </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </ed:Arc.Style>
```

Comment: I think this may be possible. Best of luck!